# Nodemailer Can't Get Started on PUG Engine

Tags: javascript, node.js, pug, node-modules, nodemailer

I've set my nodemailer engine in my .js file as below, and it works smoothly:

```
"use strict";
const nodemailer = require("nodemailer");
let config = require("../js/config")

// async..await is not allowed in global scope, must use a wrapper
async function main() {
  // create reusable transporter object using the default SMTP transport
  let transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
    host: "mail.mywebsite.com",
    port: 8889,
    secure: false, // true for 465, false for other ports
    auth: {
      user: config.user,
      pass: config.pass
    },
  });

  // verify connection configuration
    transporter.verify(function(error, success) {
        if (error) {
        console.log(error);
        } else {
        console.log("Server is ready to take our messages");
        }
    });

  // send mail with defined transport object
  let info = await transporter.sendMail({
    from: '"E-Mail Service ☕" <me@mywebsite.com>', // sender address
    to: "customer@domain.com", // list of receivers
    subject: "Your List of Selected Studies ", // Subject line
    html: "<b>Test e-mail</b> starts here. And ends <i>here</i>", // html body
  });

  console.log("Message sent: %s", info.messageId);
  // Message sent: <b658f8ca-6296-ccf4-8306-87d57a0b4321@example.com>

  // Preview only available when sending through an Ethereal account
  console.log("Preview URL: %s", nodemailer.getTestMessageUrl(info));
  // Preview URL: https://ethereal.email/message/WaQKMgKddxQDoou...
}

main().catch(console.error);
```

But when I try this code **in PUG file under the script tag**, it fails because of the **"require is not defined" problem**.

I've tried many many things but couldn't figure out how to overcome this issue, if anyone is able to give me a hand, I'll be so pleased.

Thank you for your time

Comment: Nodemailer is server-side(Node.js) library, it will not work in the browser. So putting the code in html file(pug) makes no sense. If you want to send an email from a browser you can send that message to the server using AJAX and then use nodemailer on the server.

Comment: That comment made me fix the issue

Answer (score 0):

I've solved the issue on the server side as @Molda advised.

```
router.post('/email', function(req, res, next) {
  let receiver = req.body.email;
  let studies = req.body.studies;
  let mailSpot;
  let errMessage;

  // worked my code in the question here
}
```

So.. done..!